# how to add substring functionality in full calendar using jquery?

Tags: jquery, substring, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar functionality with some events generated from a json file. The events have lengthy names. So I want to cut it by using substring(0,3) functionality. I want to use this substring function in title of the event. Where should i add substring to get ... after some 4 characters.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
//$.fn.popover.defaults.container = 'body';
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            contentHeight: 300,
            height: 200 ,
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.popover({
                    title: event.title,
                    placement: 'auto',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    animation:'true',
                    content: event.msg,
                    container: 'body'
                });
                $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
            },
            events: eventData[i].title.substring(0,5)+'..' // not working substring function
        });
```

Comment: Do mean something like this `str.substring(3, 4)` ? It will take 4 chars from the third char..

Comment: @user26409021 yes like this only.. how to implement in events ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use some CSS to achieve this?

```
.popover-title {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Unless the title is really long (like >200 characters), in which case, you might want to truncate it at the source first.